# Value resets back to maxvalue after hitting 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a calculator which shows how much the artist has left to pay to the recordcompany. In my code everytime 'artistCosts' reaches 0 it pops back up to the maximum value.
This is my code:

```
  // als er bepaalde waarden wijzigen worden de berekeningen opnieuw uitgevoerd
  change() {
    console.log('change');
    this.calculateValues();
  }

  // wijziging in dealtype
  dealtypeChanged(value) {
    this.dealType = value;
    console.log(this.dealType);
    if (this.dealType == 'licentieDeal') {
      this.recordingCosts = 0;
      this.marketingCosts = 2000;
      this.splitArtist = 25;
    } else if (this.dealType == 'distributieDeal') {
      this.recordingCosts = 0;
      this.marketingCosts = 0;
      this.splitArtist = 80;
    } else if (this.dealType == 'eigenDeal') {
      this.splitArtist = 100;
      this.artistAdvance = 0;
      this.recordingCosts = 0;
      this.marketingCosts = 0;
    } else {
      this.splitArtist = 15;
      this.artistAdvance = 2000;
      this.recordingCosts = 2000;
      this.marketingCosts = 2000;
    }
    this.change();
  }

  // berekende en verdeeld kosten tussen label en artiest op basis van recoupable velden
  calculateCosts() {
    this.artistCosts = 0;
    this.labelCosts = this.artistAdvance + this.marketingCosts + this.recordingCosts;
    if (this.recoupableArtistAdvance === true) {
      this.artistCosts = this.artistCosts + this.artistAdvance;
    }
    if (this.recoupableMarketingCosts === true) {
      this.artistCosts = this.artistCosts + this.marketingCosts;
    }
    if (this.recoupableRecordingCosts === true) {
      this.artistCosts = this.artistCosts + this.recordingCosts;
    }
  }        

// Distributes revenue between artist and label via split
      divideRevenue() {
        let artistRevenue = (this.grossRevenue * (this.splitArtist / 100));
        let labelRevenue = (this.grossRevenue * (this.splitLabel / 100));
    
        // calculation of royalties label and artist after deduction of costs
        if (artistRevenue >= this.artistCosts) {
          this.artistBalancedRecouped = 100;
          this.artistRoyalty = artistRevenue - this.artistCosts;
        } else {
          this.artistBalancedRecouped = Math.round((artistRevenue / this.artistCosts) * 100);
          this.artistRoyalty = 0;
        }
        if (labelRevenue >= this.labelCosts) {
          this.labelRoyalty = labelRevenue - this.labelCosts;
        } else {
          this.labelRoyalty = labelRevenue - this.labelCosts;
        }
        if (this.artistCosts >= this.artistCosts - artistRevenue) {
          this.artistCosts = this.artistCosts - artistRevenue;
        }
      }
```

How do let I 'artistCosts' stay at 0 when it reaches 0 without popping back up to max value.

Comment: Okay, so what is the question?

Comment: how do i get it 'artistCosts' stay at 0

Comment: Okay, we need more context to understand the entire flow of `artistCosts`. Like maybe the entire HTML template and TypeScript class files that edit the `artistCosts` variable. So that we can help you apprioprately.

Comment: Hey, I think we need more info here. First of all is the divideRevenue() the function under question? Also do you know if there are some unexpected listeners that my fire when you change artistCosts. Please help us understand by sharing how all these functions run, like suggested above maybe share the whole component.

Comment: The problem is fixed, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it after some troubleshooting, so my calculation was wrong. Still don't know why it doesn't work at the way I made it fist but this part:

```
if (this.artistCosts >= this.artistCosts - artistRevenue) {
          this.artistCosts = this.artistCosts - artistRevenue;
        }
```

I changed it to this:

```
   if (this.artistRoyalty > 0 ) {
      this.artistCosts = 0;
    } else {
      this.artistCosts = this.artistCosts - artistRevenue;
    }
```

Now `this.artistCosts` will stay also 0 when `this.artistRoyalty` goes above 0. It doesn't do a calculation anymore of multiple parameters, it just checks if the `this.artistRoyalty` is above 0. You can't do `if (this.artistRoyalty >= 0 )` I don't know why this is, if someone can explain why the first part won't work and why `if (this.artistRoyalty >= 0 )` won't work. That would be very helpfull!